# Invalid Object Name on Openquery update with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have the below query which is giving me an "Invalid object name 'E1'"

As far as I can tell my query is correct, I am wondering if it is as simple as I can not do an update to an open query with a join.  any suggestions?

```
update E1 Set e1.LILRCJ = GRDATE  from Openquery(E1_PROD_ORA, 'Select * From Proddta.F41021') E1
        Inner Join dbo.Temp2
        On E1.LiITM = IMITM
        and ltrim(rtrim(E1.LIMCU)) = E1BU
        and E1.LILOCN = Storage
    where GRDate <> '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) says:

> Any call to OPENDATASOURCE, OPENQUERY, or OPENROWSET in the FROM
>   clause is evaluated separately and independently from any call to
>   these functions used as the target of the update, even if identical
>   arguments are supplied to the two calls. In particular, filter or join
>   conditions applied on the result of one of those calls have no effect
>   on the results of the other.

This would suggest that you cannot do what you want.

You can rephrase this query, but it would help to know where `GRDATE` and the other variables with no table aliases come from.

Comment: GRDATE comes from a lookup table in SQL